# Determine users who installed an app using Google Plus API

Tags: android, google-plus

Is there an easier way to check who has installed my app using the Google plus API? I am listing out friends list where I would like to show the user if the his/her friends are using the app if not invite them?

As of now, I am getting the unique ID from the friends list and checking in backend with a database if the user is present or not.

Can somebody let me know what could be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [people.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list) API method supports a `collection` value of `connected`.

> The list of visible people in the authenticated user's circles who also use the requesting app. This list is limited to users who made their app activities visible to the authenticated user.